# Как сформировать DataFrame на основе выгрузки данных из таблицы БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, mariadb

Нужно получить DataFrame на основе выгрузки данных из таблицы БД.

Полнота данных DataFrame, структура и названия столбцов должны соответствовать таблице в БД.

Answer (score 3):

[Pandas умеет читать данные в DataFrame напрямую из таблиц БД](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) если использовать SQL Alchemy:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymsql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4")

df = pd.read_sql("select * from myshema.mytable", engine)
```

---

Можно использовать драйвер `MariaDB`, но в отличие от первого варианта, который будет работать и для `MySQL` и для `MariaDB`, вариант ниже будет работать только для `MariaDB`:

```
engine = create_engine("mariadb+pymsql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4")
```

NOTE:

> The above engine, upon first connect, will raise an error if the server version detection detects that the backing database is not MariaDB.

Comment: sqlalchemy дружит с pandas, но в описании коннектора mariadb явного пояснения не нашлось, отсюда и возник вопрос. согласен, в вопросе не хватает ссылки на коннектор mariadb.

Comment: @mr.polden2010, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#mariadb-support

Answer (score 0):

**Если использовать библиотеку mariadb**

```
import pandas as pd
import mariadb
```

Формируем соединение и курсор:

```
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
            user = 'USERNAME',
            password = 'PASSWORD',
            host = 'HOST', # 'localhost' или 'db' и т.п. зависит от настройки БД
            port = 3306)

    cur = conn.cursor()
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
```

Добавляем запрос в курсор

```
cur.execute('select * from myshema.mytable')
```

Выбираем все данные в объект lst:

```
lst = cur.fetchall()
```

Формируем DataFrame, одновременно именуем столбцы:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=[c[0] for c in cur.description])
```

Закрываем соединение с БД:

```
conn.close()
```